# How do I link a stored variable to an equation that affects multiple lights individually? (In Unity, using C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For my game I am simulating glare, and have an equation for calculating the amount of luminance on the observer's eye. Since glare is perspective-based, the equation needs to factor in that the angle the sun hitting the user's eye (in this case, the camera rig) will be changing as the user moves their head around. This in turn needs to change the intensity at each point I have a light, for each separate light.
Does anyone have any strategies for going about coding this?

I am assuming I need to call each light individually as a function, and then have the intensity be linked to the glare equation which stores the angle of light source incidence as a variable, linked to the headset.

The way a light is called upon in unity is:

```
     private Light[] lights;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     lights = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Light)) as Light[];
     foreach(Light light in lights)
     {
         light.intensity = 0;
         Debug.Log(light);
     }
 }
```

But the intensity needs to change at a rate of (10 * (illuminance value from sun)/(angle that changes based on location of headset)^2).

How would I go about storing the headset angle in this code so that the intensity is not a static number, but rather is based on a variable?

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

This is what I have right now, without inputting changes:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class GlareChange : MonoBehaviour {
         private Light[] lights;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        // SDK Object Alias|Utilities|90140
namespace VRTK
{
    using UnityEngine;
    /// <summary>
    /// The GameObject that the SDK Object Alias script is applied to will become a child of the selected SDK Object.
    /// </summary>
    [AddComponentMenu("VRTK/Scripts/Utilities/VRTK_SDKObjectAlias")]
    public class VRTK_SDKObjectAlias : MonoBehaviour
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Valid SDK Objects
        /// </summary>
        public enum SDKObject
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main camera rig/play area object that defines the player boundary.
            /// </summary>
            Boundary,
            /// <summary>
            /// The main headset camera defines the player head.
            /// </summary>
            Headset
        }
        [Tooltip("The specific SDK Object to child this GameObject to.")]
        public SDKObject sdkObject = SDKObject.Boundary;
        protected virtual void OnEnable()
        {
            VRTK_SDKManager.SubscribeLoadedSetupChanged(LoadedSetupChanged);
            ChildToSDKObject();
        }
        protected virtual void OnDisable()
        {
            if (!gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                VRTK_SDKManager.UnsubscribeLoadedSetupChanged(LoadedSetupChanged);
            }
        }
        protected virtual void LoadedSetupChanged(VRTK_SDKManager sender, VRTK_SDKManager.LoadedSetupChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (VRTK_SDKManager.ValidInstance() && gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                ChildToSDKObject();
            }
        }
        protected virtual void ChildToSDKObject()
        {
            Vector3 currentPosition = transform.localPosition;
            Quaternion currentRotation = transform.localRotation;
            Vector3 currentScale = transform.localScale;
            Transform newParent = null;
            switch (sdkObject)
            {
                case SDKObject.Boundary:
                    newParent = VRTK_DeviceFinder.PlayAreaTransform();
                    break;
                case SDKObject.Headset:
                    newParent = VRTK_DeviceFinder.HeadsetTransform();
                    break;
            }
            transform.SetParent(newParent);
            transform.localPosition = currentPosition;
            transform.localRotation = currentRotation;
            transform.localScale = currentScale;


lights = Find(typeof(Light)) as Light[];
        foreach (Light light in lights)
        {
                //EYE = illuminance from source, in this case the sun
                //q = angle from viewer
            light.intensity = (10*EYE/(Mathf.Atan2(currentPosition/SUNPOSITION));
            Debug.Log(light);
        }
    }
}

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }
}
```

And this is from the unity site as an example of changing light intensity from variables:

```
      using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float duration = 1.0F;
    public Light lt;
    void Start() {
        lt = GetComponent<Light>();
    }
    void Update() {
        float phi = Time.time / duration * 2 * Mathf.PI;
        float amplitude = Mathf.Cos(phi) * 0.5F + 0.5F;
        lt.intensity = amplitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're using in the Update/Draw loop? That might help with specifics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each update cycle, you'll need to loop through your Light sources and get a world-space vector representing the distance between the light and the headset/user in relation to the world Normal. This can be used to compute the angle between the headset (A), the light source (C), and the World Normal (B).

*Note: depending on your coordinate spaces, you may need to swap signs or operands)*

`d(light) = light.Position - user.Position`

The angle θ can be computed by using this distance to construct right triangle ABC and then solving for the tangent of angle ABC using trigonometry (again, signs and operands may need to be adjusted depending on coordinate spaces in use):

`tan(θ) = (user.Position.Y - light.Position.Y)/(user.Position.X - light.Position.X)`

Presumably, each of your light sources has a base, or absolute intensity. Use this base (absolute) luminosity value in to calculate the actual (apparent) luminosity as seen by your user, as given by your equation:

`L(act) = 10 * L(abs)/θ^2`

The Unity framework may have built-in functionality that performs these tasks for you, but this or something similar is what those components would be doing under the hood. If you're looking for Unity-specific guidance, I would recommend posting to the [Game Development SE site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you! I found a way to call on a Vector3 command that tracks the location of the headset, but wasn't sure how to convert that to distance from where the sun would be, letting me place a value for theta. This definitely helps put me in the right direction.